# Alternative for queryCommandValue("FontSize")

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

After googling a lot I am not able to find a solution for `queryCommandValue("FontSize")` in Javascript.

I have gone through various font sizes in HTML CSS like pt, px, em, mm etc.,

`queryCommandValue("FontSize")` is returning values from 1-7, but I need values ranging from `5pt` to `48pt`.

I got some code in MSHTML, but that is not javascript.

Is there any alternative to get this?

Comment: What are you trying to find exactly?

Comment: I wish to get font-size when some text is selected or when mouse is clicked in the text

Comment: you want to make a page where when you click on any text in the page it returns the font size of the text?

Comment: I have a text editor with font size and name in toolbar, I am able to show font-name, but font size is displayed wrong, when some text is selected (feature similar to MS word is needed)

Comment: Are you talking about from a developer's perspective or a user's perspective?

Comment: Developer perspective

Comment: How to get some solution for this?

Comment: You need to post either a link to your site, or all the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

In order to see font size from a developer's perspective, using the Google Chrome browser.

1. Right click on the element in question
2. Select `Inspect Element`
3. On the right side of the window that will pop up, look under `Styles`
4. Look for a value entitles `font-size`

If the value is a percentage, it is a percentage of parent element's font-size

If the font size is not stated anywhere, it is the browser's default size for that element

Comment: But I want to get the font size of text in javascript. With chromes' `Inspect element`, firebug or IE developer tool, we will get info for checking. But I need to implement the functionality that when some text is selected whose font is Arial 10pt, then these values should be displayed. Hope it is clear,what I am looking for.

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this could be

```
document.querySelectorAll("font");
```

,which would also return multiple font definitions in case the selection holds such things.